# passport.authenticate() middleware removing all the session keys

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session, passport.js

I am storing the url in a **returnTo** key in the session and it persists in the session as long as the **passport.authenticate()** middleware is not called, after calling this middleware my session keys are lost.
This is my **isLoggedin** function which stores the url in the **req.session.returnTo** :

```js
isLoggedin: async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
      req.flash("error", "Please login");
      await req.session.save();
      return res.redirect("/login");
    }
    next();
  },
```

After the ("/login") page is rendered it sends a post request to ("/login") to authenticate the user.

This is the post request handler, I have console.log the session to show the value of session before and after the middleware **passport.authenticate()** is called :

```js
router
  .route("/login")
  .get(authentication.loginrender)
  .post(
    (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.session);
      next();
    },
    passport.authenticate("local", {
      failureFlash: false,
      failureRedirect: "/login",
    }),
    (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.session);
      next();
    },
    authentication.loginuser
  );
```

Here is the output in the console after logging in, before authenticate there is **"returnTo"** in the session but after passport.authenticate() it is lost :

[CONSOLE OUTPUT IMAGE AFTER LOGGIN IN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzIDW.png)

This is my app.js file :

```js
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.engine("ejs", ejsmate);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieparser());
const sessionConfig = {
  secret: "thisshouldbeabettersecret!",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  },
};
app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new localstrategy(User.authenticate()));
app.use(flash());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Can anybody please help me, I have been really struggling to solve this from the past few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same error and after searching a lot, it seems that keeping session may lead to security flaws, so since passport 6, authenticate automatically lead to session wipe.

You can work around this adding

keepSessionInfo: true

to your passport.authentificate but you will get back the security issue.

to solve the issue, you need to store the values in another way (redis for exemple).

Comment: Can't believe this option is undocumented besides a changelog mention and a passport medium post: https://medium.com/passportjs/fixing-session-fixation-b2b68619c51d